# Why can't login mysql with local ip?

Tags: mysql, connection

I can login mysql with `127.0.0.1`.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

Now grant `192.168.31.52` (my localhost's ip in lan )  permission.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'192.168.31.52' identified by 'xxxx' with grant option;
flush  privileges;
exit;
```

Try to login local mysql server with :

```
mysql -h 192.168.31.52 -u root -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.31.52' (111 "Connection refused")
```

Why can't link mysql with ip `192.168.31.52`?

Comment: You're allowing the access to your MySQL server from 192.168.31.52 IP but you're trying to connect to a server with 192.168.31.52 IP. The input connection and output connection are two different things. Can you edit and add more information like IP of source and destination machines, for example.

Comment: The mysql server  located in my local pc which its lan ip is 192.168.31.52,link from itself to itself.

Comment: This question is confusing;  In order to connect with you 192.168.31.52 must explicitly grant access.  This doesn’t appear to have been done based on the error you received

Comment: it_is_a_literature, Did you try to comment "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" of your my.cnf file and restart the service? Take care of consecuencies if it works [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552680/bind-address-and-mysql-server ]

Answer (score 0):

Try this from another user.  Root logins from a remote connection are normally disallowed.  Also, the user from that IP address is considered to be a separate user, and must be created just like the one on localhost. See you users with:

```
SELECT host,user,password FROM mysql.user;
```